# How do ESRI and QGIS calculate scale values of geographic projections?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, scale

Does anyone know how (from which location) scale values are calculated in ESRI products and QGIS for geographic projections?

The only thing I've noticed is that QGIS is changing scales when you pan for instance in WGS84 while ESRI scale is fixed and independent from the viewport.

I am guessing that ESRI takes the length of a degree on the equator and treats it as linear unit for scale calculation and QGIS is taking a point from the viewport (centre?) - but these are just my factless assumptions as I wasn't able to find anything on the net.

Comment: I notice that this question has not been answered, or even commented on, in the two months since it was asked.  As it stands you are asking two questions, one about ArcGIS for Desktop, and the other about QGIS, and so I think it may be suffering from being too broad.  I recommend that you edit it to focus just on whichever is more important to you.  The other can always be researched/asked about separately.

Comment: Just in case anyone else is wondering, QGIS does indeed use the current latitude. It calculates the distance in meters at the mean latitude, then scales that distance to the visible map extent, then converts it from meters to inches to get an inch : meters distance. Details in the source code here: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/07a570fd0560d1cb31a179b95e75cc5d5caf649b/src/core/qgsscalecalculator.cpp#L50